# Showing $f(a) \in V$ but $f(x_n) \notin V$ for every $n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces and let $f: X
> \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Let $a \in X$ and suppose $f$ is not
>   continuous in $a$. Prove that there exists an open subset $V$ in $Y$
>   and a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$ and
>   $f(a) \in V$, but $f(x_n) \notin V$ for every $n$.

---

My attempt:

Let $a \in X$ and suppose that $f$ is not continuous in $a$. Then, by definition, there exists an open $V \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open in $X$. Also, because $f$ is not continuous in $a$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ such that $(x_n) \rightarrow a$, but $f(x_n) \not\rightarrow f(a)$. Since $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open in $X$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ we have that $$B_X(x_n, \frac{1}{n}) \not\subset f^{-1}(V). $$ Then I'm not sure what I can conclude from this. Can I just suppose that $f(a) \in V$? (I think not).

Some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $f$ is not continuous at $x=a$, then there exists a sequence $x_n\to a$, with $f(x_n)\not\to f(a)$. If $f(x_n)\not\to f(a)$, then one can pick an $\varepsilon>0$ and a subsequence $f(x_{n_k})$, such that
$$
d\big(f(x_{n_k}),f(a)\big)\ge \varepsilon.
$$
Take then as $V=\{y\in Y : d\big(y,f(a)\big)<\varepsilon/2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ being discontinuous means that there is an open $V \subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open. $f$ being discontinuous *at $a$* means specifically that there is an open $V\subseteq Y$ with $f(a) \in V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open in $X$. So yes, you can just suppose that.